# Laravel 5 deployment to Heroku - Background image not loading

Tags: php, css, laravel, heroku

Hi im trying to deploy my Laravel 5 application to Heroku and everything is working as suposed , everything but the background image.
The image loads fine in localhost and i dont know what to do.
This is the website : http://young-peak-2652.herokuapp.com/

I have this css :

> .mid{
>       background-image: url("../../assets/images/golden_gate.jpg");
>   }

in error log of console it says that he doesnt find the path, i even created a copy of assets repository in the root of the project and it still doesnt find the image.

Comment: What is the absolute URL of the image? It's trying to load: http://young-peak-2652.herokuapp.com/assets/images/golden_gate.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you've deployed correctly? I don't see this line anywhere in your CSS

Comment: in my pc it is C:\wamp\www\projeto\assets\images\golden_gate.jpg since the application root is 'projeto' take your conclusions

Comment: how do u dont see? just click mid div and its there ...

Comment: you cannot go back directories prior to your root folder (e.g. `path/to/laravel/public`).
so you need to move your assets folder inside your public folder and change paths on your code.